# Let $F$ be a field of characteristic not $2$, and let $K$ be an extension of $F$ with $[K: F] = 2$. Show that $K = F (\sqrt{a})$ for some $a\in F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

**Let $F$ be a field of characteristic not $2$, and let $K$ be an extension
of $F$ with $[K: F] = 2$. Show that $K = F (\sqrt{a})$ for some $a\in F$; that
is, show that $K = F(\alpha)$ with $\alpha^2= a\in F$. Moreover, show that $K$ is
Galois over $F$.**

I do not know how to try the first part, could someone help me please? For the second part I am using the following theorem:

**Let $K$ be a finite extension of $F$. Then $K/F$ is Galois if
and only if $|Gal(K/F)| = [K:F]$**

Because $Gal(K/F)=\left \{ id,\sigma  \right \}  $ where $\sigma$ is such that $\sigma(\sqrt{a})=-\sqrt{a}$, then $K$ is Galois over $F$.

Comment: It’s the Quadratic Formula.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pick $\beta \in K\setminus F$. Then $1,\beta,\beta^2$ are $F$-linear dependent, but we know that $1,\beta$ are not. Hence $\beta^2+p\beta+q=0$ with $p,q\in F$. Let $\alpha=\beta+\frac12\cdot p$ (this is where the characteristic is used: otherwise we are not allowed to divide by $2$). Now verify that $\alpha^2\in F$.

Comment: I do not understand why you make that substitution, could you explain better? Why is the characteristic used there?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the minimal polynomial $x^2+ax+b$, then translate by $a/2$. We are allowed to do so since the characteristic is not 2, then the minimal polynomial becomes $x^2-d$, hence $F=K(\sqrt{d})$ as wanted.

Comment: That is the minimal polynomial of what?

Comment: Of your degree 2 extension.

Comment: I don’t think that extensions have minimal polynomials; rather an element of the extension has a minimal polynomial. In this case, it’s minimal polynomial of $x+\frac a2$